# Get a substr of a long stream

Tags: php, string, stream, file-get-contents, substr

I want to read only some finite characters of beginnings of some long streams, but `file_get_contents` does not support seek operations, and I must first read the whole stream to extract the desired part of the string with `substr`.

As my resources are limited and the speed of the application is very important, how can I achieve this more efficiently?

Comment: What streams in particular? Would [`fopen`](http://php.net/fopen) do?

Comment: @minitech an URL for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your configuration, [`fopen`](http://php.net/fopen) could do the trick. From an example on that page:

```
$handle = fopen("http://www.example.com/", "r");
```

Then you can use [`fread`](http://php.net/fread) to read the requisite number of bytes, and then just [close](http://php.net/fclose) it.

Comment: The speed of my application now in 10X